# Document load event not being called after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have the following function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    window.addEventListener("load", function (){
        alert("hello");
});
```

It works on the first run, but then stops working when I hit the refresh button.

If I empty the cache or hard reload, it works again once.

What is going on? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the handler outside of jQuery's `document.ready()`:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function (){
 ...
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  ...
};
```

On the first run the page might take time to load external resources (such as images). During that time `jQuery(document).ready(...)` is called.

When it finishes loading the external resources, the `load` event is fired and the function works correctly.

Weirdly enough, upon refresh, the resources are already cached, so the `window.load` event is fired so fast and occurs **before** `jQuery(document).ready()`, and since you add the event handler after the event was fired, the handler is not called. When you cleared the cache it worked again.

---

Alternatively, you can check the document for completion first like so:

```
function document_loaded(){
    // To be called when the document is loaded.
    ...
};

document.readyState == "complete" ? document_loaded() : window.addEventListener("load", document_loaded);
```

This will work no matter where you place the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a script each time the page is loaded the best way is to put the code directly into the main function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert("hello");
};
```

From the documentation : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ :

> Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the
> page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to
> execute.

If you want to wait also that your assets are loaded you should write:

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```